Selenium Scraper Issue "WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'"
I am encountering an error when trying to use Selenium with Scrapy. The error message is: WebDriver.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
I am using a custom middleware in middlewares.py where I only use the executable_path keyword argument in one spot. According to the Selenium documentation, this is a valid argument and should be used as shown below:
class selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service(
    executable_path=None,
    port: int = 0,
    service_args: List[str] | None = None,
    log_output: int | str | IO[Any] | None = None,
    env: Mapping[str, str] | None = None,
    **kwargs
)[source]


Here is the relevant section of my middlewares.py:
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumMiddleware
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class CustomSeleniumMiddleware(SeleniumMiddleware):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        settings = crawler.settings
        driver_name = settings.get('SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME')
        driver_executable_path = settings.get('SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH')
        driver_arguments = settings.get('SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS', [])
        browser_executable_path = settings.get('SELENIUM_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_PATH', None)

        options = Options()
        for argument in driver_arguments:
            options.add_argument(argument)

        service = ChromeService(executable_path=driver_executable_path)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

        middleware = cls(driver_name, driver_executable_path, driver_arguments, browser_executable_path, driver)
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return middleware

    def __init__(self, driver_name, driver_executable_path, driver_arguments, browser_executable_path, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        super().__init__(driver_name, driver_executable_path, driver_arguments, browser_executable_path)

    @staticmethod
    def create_options(arguments):
        chrome_options = Options()
        for argument in arguments:
            chrome_options.add_argument(argument)
        return chrome_options

Based on the Selenium documentation, I expected that using the executable_path keyword argument would correctly set up the Chrome service. However, I am getting the error that it is an unexpected keyword argument.
Here are the steps I have tried so far:
Verified the ChromeService class from Selenium documentation, which indicates that executable_path is a valid argument.
Ensured that the executable_path provided is correct and points to the chromedriver executable.
Updated Selenium to the latest version to ensure compatibility.
Despite these steps, I am still encountering the error. I am not sure if I am misinterpreting the documentation or if there is an issue elsewhere in my code or environment setup.

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide the full traceback at least.

Make sure you are using an updated version of selenium
